# Call .py file in ajax

Tags: ajax, odoo

Is it possible call below xmlrpc.py  with ajax?

In terminal work fine after call
**my@ubuntu:~/custom_module/xml_rpc$ python xmlrpc.py**

```
import xmlrpclib

username = 'admin' 
pwd = 'admin'
dbname = 'db_1'

sock_common = xmlrpclib.ServerProxy('http://localhost:8069/xmlrpc/common')
uid = sock_common.login(dbname, username, pwd)
sock = xmlrpclib.ServerProxy('http://localhost:8069/xmlrpc/object')

partner = {
           'name': 'User 1'
        }

contact_ids = sock.execute(dbname, uid, pwd, 'res.partner', 'search', [])
```